# laravel query binding failed using "<" or ">"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, binding

lets asume, i have database, and table name "art".
in table art theres fields (art_id,rank)
i have dummy data like this:

```
art_id   rank
1        1
2        2
3        3
4        4
5        5
6        11
7        11
8        11
```

then when i want to select from art where rank > 3

so when i use this code:

```
DB::select('select * from art WHERE rank > ?',array(3));
```

it return many row

but, when i use this code :

```
DB::select('select * from art WHERE rank > 3 ');
```

it return only 2 row..

anybody can explain me why this happening? its that because array bindings failed or something?

edit : im using enum in data type for rank field.
when im using integer in data type for rank field, both codes are work fine.

Solution : using integer may works perfectly with both codes, but i still wondering why enum can't works perfectly with first code.

Comment: Doesn't seem plausible. It should be working same in both codes

Comment: yeah im using enum for rank field. so when im change integer for rank field both codes are work fine.

thanks for your response @Hanky웃Panky

Comment: Why would you use `enum` when rank is clearly more fit to be an `integer`?

Comment: @Marwelln Because rank field clearly define 1 to 11 so i used enum beside integer. Thank you for your response.